# external drive MAY be failing, or may be fine... any way to check?

Tags: external-hard-drive

EDIT: to make it clear, I'm looking for **testing** methods, not debugging tips.

I have been using two external hard drives with my MacBook Pro for redundant data backups. Well, I started having signs of trouble, like spontaneous drive disconnects and the need for First Aid to repair a drive to get it to mount again.

I also was using somewhat buggy software.

So long story short, the next thing you know I had lost most of my data on one drive (all corrupted or blown away) and the other drive was about 1% corrupted as well.

The problem could have been

- Hardware: bad USB hub that I was using?
- Hardware: fault in the drives?
- OS X: Just a normal result of disconnecting without ejecting?
- Software: I was using a program that is fairly badly designed and I wouldn't have put it past it to mess up my data

I will not use the software again. I will stop using the **hub** for now. But I don't know if I can trust these drives.

I found a lot of threads about "stress testing" brand new drives. This is not quite the same situation. This is more like, there is a very good chance the drive is already bad, but its failures may be intermittent at this point.

**Is there any hard drive test software that could verify they are working, or determine what is wrong with them?**

Comment: In your first paragraph I had the same issue. My problem was a bad 3.0 cable. You'd be surprised how many bad cables make it to the customer. At this point I don't trust external drives (pocket sized drives) as a backup option. I now use a NAS with 4 drives and use RAID 5. It's more expensive, it's worth it for me for all the WORK and sweat I have backed up along with personal files too. One drive can fail and I still have safe data. I have a backup drive on stand by to replace any drive that may fail in the future.

Comment: Troubleshoot: start by swapping out cables. Think of it this way, imagine driving your car and there is a monkey under your hood pulling off the battery cable every time he feels like it. It could cause problems with your internals no? Intermittent connectivity sounds like cable issues.

Comment: The problem is that I need a way to do thorough testing. They seem to work most of the time, so it's not obvious at this point that it wasn't a bad USB hub, or buggy software. It's no problem to get them to work for a short time, the problem is I need a way to be confident they will **keep** working.

Comment: A cable is very cheap. The connectivity problem sounds like a bad cable. Good luck.

Comment: If you want to check the drive, you can always check their S.M.A.R.T. data. This data shows for example the bad sector count. There are many programs allowing you to do this, and there's a lot of documentation about it online. I can't name an implementation for Mac, but Google or other users can help you with this